# Spring SpEL: exception using T() function to load Enum in combobox

Tags: spring, enums, spring-el

I'm looking for a way to load an enum in a combobox (i'm using JSTL) without place it in a model attribute I'm using SPEL for that reason and I found different example for use it. I'm trying with this solution

```
<form:select path="status">
   <option class="" value=""><s:message code="optLabel" /></option>
   <c:forEach var="enum" items="${T(com.mypackage.enums.Status).values()}">
     <option>...</option>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

and with this solution

```
<select> 
  <option th:each="elem: ${T(com.mypackage.enums.Status).values()}" th:value="${elem.val()}" th:text="#{elem.val()}" value="BAZ">BAZ</option> 
</select>
```

but I have this Excpetion in runtime "The function T must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified"

What should I do?

This is enum class:

```
public enum Status { 

VALID("valid"), OLD("old");

private final String val;

Status(String val) {
    this.val = val;
}

public String getVal() {
    return val;
}
}
```

Another clarification..if I write

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
...    
<s:eval expression="T(com.mypackage.enums.Status).VALID == T(com.mypackage.enums.Status).VALID" var="isValid" /> 
        <c:if test="${isValid}"> 
           isValid 
        </c:if>
```

This works fine! This makes me think that the function T ( ) is found and executed in this way. So, why I have that exception?

Comment: Because you aren't using SpEL. IN a JSP the normal EL is used, in spring configs Spring is parsing the expressions. The same applies to `s:eval` tags Spring is parsing the expression.

Comment: Oh..so the examples found on Internet not working at all! How can I load enum in combobox without passing it in a model?

Comment: Your post is confusing in this regard, are you using JSP or are you using Thymeleaf?

Comment: Then I wonder why you thought the second option would work as that is Thymeleaf and not JSP. But alas, with JSP there is no way in doing so, you should use the `s:eval` tag for that or use a scriptlet but with plain EL it won't work. I would add it to the model as that is what the model is intended for.

Comment: i don't know how to use eval to load enum in combobox. Any example?

Comment: You can use the normal SpEL expression to get the values, store it in a variable and use that in normal EL. Just put the expression you want in the eval tag.